Does there exist a "bounded interpolation scheme" for functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$?
I'm not sure if this fits more in math SE or MO, as I'm looking for specific answers but the question has some room for discussion.
Also, my background is not in numerics, so maybe some wording might come across as whacky, but I will give a precise definition.
What I'm asking about are interpolation schemes in the following sense: An interpolation scheme for a space of functions $F$ is a pair $S=((e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}},d)$, with:

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}:e_n\in F$,
$d$ is a "nice enough" metric on $F$,
For each $f\in F$, there exists a (computable) sequence of coefficients $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the sequence $f_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}c_ie_i$ converges to $f$ wrt. $d$.

Some examples of interpolation schemes in this sense are fourier series, taylor series, Tchebyshev Interpolation on their respective function spaces etc.
Now say we are dealing with a nice-enough space $F$ of functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$, for example piecewise-continuous, of bounded variation, (maybe even computable?), anything nice enough to answer the question but still as general as possible. Ideally, $d$ is induced by the norm on an ambient normed vector space $F_{\text{amb}}\supseteq F$ of functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.
What I noticed is that with all the interpolation schemes I found, the coefficients can vanish or blow up incredibly to allow for cancellations at points of high variation for ugly functions.

What I'm interested in is: Does there exist an interpolation scheme on $F$ of (uniformly) bounded coefficients? Meaning is there an interesting space $F$ of functions $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with an interpolation scheme such that we can always guarantee all $|c_n|< C$ for some $C$, or atleast a sequence $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that all $|c_n|<C_n$?
For example, Taylor series can not be such an interpolation scheme because for all $c\in \mathbb{R}_+$ there exists an $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=c$.
As I didn't find anything concrete, I'm keeping the question a bit open as in you have some leeway in chosing suitable $F$ and $d$, but please leave out trivial examples. I'm specifically interested in continuous functions with $d$ induced by the $\mathscr{L}_2$-norm.

A comment to the choice of words of "interpolation scheme": At the moment it seems like I'm more interested in something that should be named an "approximation scheme" than interpolation. I was originally interested in interpolation as in figuring out the approximation from a stream of (at each time step) finitely information, but as I now question the existence of nontrivial "approximation schemes" with the asked property at all, I settled for that definition for the time being.
